# How to find if a list consists of ordered perfect squares in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to return *true* if the *list* is a *square list*, that is, `true` if the list is of the type `'(0 1 4 9 16)`.

This is what I have (below) but it does check if the list is ordered. That is, my code will return `true` if a list is `'(4 0 1 9 16)`. How can I modify my code?

```
(define (squares? lst)
  (cond
   ((null? lst) #t)
   ((not( integer? (sqrt(car lst)))) #f)
   (else  (squares? (cdr lst)))))
```

for a list of the type `'(4 0 1 9 16)` I am going to obtain `true` with the above code, but the answer should be `false`, because my list is not `'(0 1 4 9 16)`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the list also have to be "complete"? That is, is `(1 4 16)` a "square list" or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the true spirit of functional programming, you should attempt to split the problem in smaller parts, and to reuse and combine existing procedures.

Assuming that the list doesn't need to be "complete", we just need to create and invoke one extra procedure that checks if the list is sorted:

```
(define (square? lst)
  (and (all-squares? lst)
       (sorted? lst)))

(define (all-squares? lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) #t)
    ((not (integer? (sqrt (car lst)))) #f)
    (else (all-squares? (cdr lst)))))

(define (sorted? lst)
  (apply <= lst))
```

Just for fun, we can also rewrite `all-squares?` taking advantage of existing procedures:

```
(define (square? lst)
  (and (andmap (compose integer? sqrt) lst)
       (apply <= lst)))
```

Anyway, it'll work as expected with either implementation:

```
(square? '(0 1 4 9 16))
=> #t

(square? '(4 0 1 9 16))
=> #f
```

Comment: Since `<` can take any number of arguments, the `(sorted? lst)` form in the definition of `square?` can be replaced with `(apply < lst)`.

Comment: @MichaelMacLeod good catch! I updated it. Better to use `<=`, in case there are duplicates.

Comment: Bravo! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could pass additionally last checked number

```
(define (squares? lst last-n)
```

and then check if `(car lst)` is bigger than `last-n`

```
   ((not (< last-n (car lst)) #f)
```

Oh, and also, don't forget to pass new `last-n` to `squares?`

```
   (else (squares? (cdr lst) (car lst)))
```

---

You can define `last-n` as *optional* parameter, ie `(define (squares? lst . last-n))` but then you have to access value by `(car last-n)`, because all optional parameters are passed joined together as a list.